# Strongswan Installation for CentOS 7

Tags: yum, ipsec, rpm, radius, strongswan

I'm want to use IKEv2 VPN on a CentOS 7.* VMs, and I want to Authenticate the users with our RADIUS server.

Currently, I'm using `yum install strongswan` command to install the strongswan repo, but it doesn't load the eap-radius plugin by default.

is there any way to load eap-radius plugin with using the compilation methods.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing from EPEL, the *eap-radius* plugin is shipped in the *strongswan-tnc-imcvs* package for some reason. Try installing that before starting to compile strongSwan yourself.

Comment: You saved my life :)